# Swift class conforming to Objective-C protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, chromecast

In Objective-C I have the [the following protocol](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_device_scanner_listener-p):

```
@protocol GCKDeviceScannerListener <NSObject>    
@optional

- (void)deviceDidComeOnline:(GCKDevice *)device;
- (void)deviceDidGoOffline:(GCKDevice *)device;
- (void)deviceDidChange:(GCKDevice *)device;

@end
```

When trying to conform to this protocol in Swift Xcode 6.1 autocompletes it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GCKDeviceScannerListener {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner();
        deviceScanner.addListener(self);
        deviceScanner.startScan();
        println("scanning");
    }

    func deviceDidComeOnline(device: GCKDevice!) {
        println("deviceDidComeOnline()");
    }

    func deviceDidGoOffline(device: GCKDevice!) {
        println("deviceDidGoOffline()");
    }

    func deviceDidChange(device: GCKDevice!) {
        println("deviceDidChange()");
    }

}
```

The code compiles and seemingly runs ok on the simulator. However, none of the listener functions are ever triggered. Everything works 100% of the time when running [the demo project from Google](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios) written in Objective-C only. Because of the last part I'm assuming that the there aren't any problems with the network or hardware or anything like that.

It could be that I have missed something important from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender, but **I would like to know if the Swift code itself is correct according to the protocol**. As the protocol only has optional functions it's hard to know if it's right.

Comment: You can test the protocol conformance of your ViewController by using `self.respondsToSelector("deviceDidComeOnline:")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with this library, but I think you should keep the reference to `GCKDeviceScanner`.

Try:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GCKDeviceScannerListener {

    var deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        deviceScanner.addListener(self)
        deviceScanner.startScan()
        println("scanning")
    }
```

Comment: I was going to downvote your answer because I thought it had nothing to do with my question, but then I looked at your SO score and then tried it out, and it worked. :) Do you know or care to comment on why it works like this?

Comment: In your original code, `deviceScanner` is deallocated when `viewDidLoad` returns. I think, that silently cancels the scanning, and removes its listeners.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation on Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) is long and complex.

It's easiest to think of `optional` protocol methods like Optional closures, and you can use it with optional chaining.

```
@objc class Something {
    var delegate: GCKDeviceScannerListener?

    func someCallback() {
        delegate?.deviceDidComeOnline?(device)
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is what OP asking for